# How to overcome this compilation(Nuitka) error for python

Tags: compiler-errors, python-3.6, nuitka, ubuntu-16.10

I'm just starting to know about python language, and i just know the basics.
I am finding problem when trying to compile a small command in ubuntu using nuitka.

Note : The python version i'm using here is python 3.6
Here is my $ sample.py $.

```
    Print ("Hello user.")
```

And here is the command line i used to compile the code...

```
    nuitka --recurse-on --python-version=3.6 sample.py
```

When i use this command, i get this as output...

```
sample.build/CompiledAsyncgenType.c: In function
‘Nuitka_Asyncgen_unwrap_value’:
sample.build/CompiledAsyncgenType.c:994:9: warning: implicit declaration              
of function ‘_PyGen_SetStopIterationValue’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     _PyGen_SetStopIterationValue(((_PyAsyncGenWrappedValue*)result)->agw_val );            

     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
sample.build/CompiledAsyncgenType.o: In function     
`Nuitka_Asyncgen_unwrap_value.isra.9':
CompiledAsyncgenType.c:(.text+0x118c): undefined reference to     
`_PyGen_SetStopIterationValue'
sample.build/CompiledAsyncgenType.o: In function  
`Nuitka_AsyncgenAsend_throw':
CompiledAsyncgenType.c:(.text+0x2337): undefined reference to     
`_PyGen_SetStopIterationValue'
sample.build/CompiledAsyncgenType.o: In function  
`Nuitka_AsyncgenAthrow_throw':
CompiledAsyncgenType.c:(.text+0x295f): undefined reference to    
`_PyGen_SetStopIterationValue'
sample.build/CompiledAsyncgenType.o: In function   
`Nuitka_AsyncgenAthrow_iternext':
CompiledAsyncgenType.c:(.text+0x30e8): undefined reference to    
`_PyGen_SetStopIterationValue'
sample.build/CompiledAsyncgenType.o: In function   
`Nuitka_AsyncgenAsend_tp_iternext':
CompiledAsyncgenType.c:(.text+0x37b7): undefined reference to     
`_PyGen_SetStopIterationValue'
sample.build/CompiledAsyncgenType.o:CompiledAsyncgenType.c:(.text+0x3fe7):    
more undefined references to `_PyGen_SetStopIterationValue' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
scons: *** [sample.exe] Error 1
```

Please help me resolve this issue guys!!...

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems that will also cause failure in CPython (the reference implementation).

1. Print with an uppercase P does is not built into Python.  The built
   in function begins with a lower case p.
2. A single line program should not be indented.